# multiple feature scatter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a scatterplot in ggplot2 where points with "Changed" equal to "yes" are red dots, the rest remaining grey, while points with "Significant" equal to "significant" have additional boarder in green, and the rest has a grey boarder.
Here is my try:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Changed)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = Significant)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red","grey", "grey")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

and input data:

```
structure(list(a = c(4.31316551, 5.7663368, 2.49063318, 5.83090286, 
3.11188057, 9.58084417, 4.08696886, 3.11188057, 6.43800344, 1.77771123, 
4.22594833), b = c(0.848363512, 0.045492721, 0.049883076, 0.136202457, 
0.572585532, 0.175069609, 0.000782666, 0.848363512, 0.254619199, 
0.378181529, 0.848363512), Significant = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Change = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "Significant", "Change"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Could you add a data sample please

Comment: please see the update version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different ways of doing this:

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, size=3, mapping = aes(fill=Change, color=Significant)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "red")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grey","green"))

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  geom_point(data=df[df$Significant == "no",], color="grey", size=5) + 
  geom_point(data=df[df$Significant == "yes",], color="green", size=5) +
  geom_point(size=3, mapping = aes(color=Change)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grey","red"))
```

Comment: thanks, I like the first one, just one more question, say there is a third specifier, e.g. a must be > 4, so the colors are even applied, otherwise they remain grey.

Comment: I'd recommend just adding the computed conditions as new columns to the data set.